# Custom Post Type: How to display all of same taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, taxonomy

Isn't there a permalink structure that will essentially list out all `categories` of a certain `post type`?

```
function create_faqs_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'faqs',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'FAQs' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'FAQ' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'the-faqs')
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_faqs_post_type' );

function create_faq_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'faqs_categories',
        'faqs',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'FAQs Categories',
            'query_var' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_faq_taxonomy' );
```

This is the code I've using to register the custom post type `faqs` and then register a taxonomy for it.

Isn't there a permalink structure that will essentially automatically list out all `faqs` of a certain taxonomy? Or do I need to create a custom template and query it specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dcolumbus

You can do a permalink rewrite when you register the taxonomy using the following:

'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'faqcategories', 'with_front' => false ),

Then site.com/faqcategories should pull them and site.com/faqcategories/easy should get them for you for the 'easy' term.

If I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: So let's say I have a CPT called `Books` ... then I have a taxonomy called `Genre` and a genre of `Horror` ... What I'm essentially trying to do is find out if I can list all "horror" books on a single page without having to create a custom Template for that query.

http://www.mysite.com/books/horror/ <- shows all books associated with the `Horror` taxonomy.

Comment: Christopher? Are you still around?

Comment: Sorry, been hiking. Jonathan Christopher did a good write up on this a while ago. You can find it here: http://mondaybynoon.com/20110520/revisiting-custom-post-types-taxonomies-permalinks-slugs/. Note that the taxonomy should be registered before the post type (that screwed me up in the past).

Comment: What on earth? I've ALWAYS registered the CPT before registering the associated Taxonomy. What does that cause?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$catArgs = array(
        'taxonomy'=>'faqs_categories'
        // post_type isn't a valid argument, no matter how you use it.
        );
$categories = get_categories('taxonomy=faqs_categories&post_type=faqs'); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
  <div class="faqs-cat"><?php echo $category->name; ?></div>
    <?php
    $postArgs = array(
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type'=>'faqs',
        'cat'=>$category->cat_ID,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'faqs_categories'
                )
            )
        );
     query_posts($postArgs) ?>
    <ul>
         <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <li><a><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();
```

Edited but original source [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-all-categories-in-a-custom-taxonomy-and-post-types-under-each-of-those-cat#post-2678647). Good luck, I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, yeah... so there's no permalink structure that will give me the result I'm looking for. It's going to have to be a custom template?

Comment: You could possibly implement this as a filter, but I don't know of any other ways, however I'm not saying that there isn't an alternative. I've had to use this implementation a handful of times, as I haven't found a quicker alternative. Cheers